# What is _id in Object returned by a promise?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm using Promise module in Node.js to read the files in a directory as below.

```
var promise = require("promise");
var fs = require("fs");
var readdir = promise.denodeify(fs.readdir);

var readDirPromise = readdir("/Users/sashi/Documents/javascript/telegram")
    readDirPromise
Promise {
  _75: 0,
  _83: 1,
  _18: 
   [ '.DS_Store',
     'arica.txt',
     'iquitos.txt',
     'lapaz.txt',
     'puntaarenas.txt',
     'testingSashi_bot.js' ],
  _38: null }
```

What are the _75,_83,_18,_38? Will they always be the same numbers? As in to get my filelist can I always do

```
console.log(readDirPromise._18)
```

Or do the numbers change depending on the situation?

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit:**

I experimented a bit. It looks like _83 is used to signify whether the promise is resolved or not.

- _83:0 (Promise not resolved)
- _83:1 (Promise is resolved and no errors)
- _83:2 (Promise is resolved but there is an error somewhere)

See below.

```
function readJSON(filename){
    return readFile(filename,'utf8').then(JSON.parse,console.log);
}
```

When promise is not resolved yet.

```
readJSON("./Places/arica.txt")
Promise { _75: 0, _83: 0, _18: null, _38: null }
```

If the Promise is resolved but there is an error.

```
 Promise {
  _75: 0,
  _83: 2,
  _18: SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (/Users/sashi/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/sashi/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/sashi/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:172:11),
  _38: null }
```

If the Promise is resolved without an error.

```
Promise {
  _75: 0,
  _83: 1,
  _18: 
   { name: 'lapaz',
     description: 'La Paz is the capital of Bolivia. It is one of my favorite cities because its crazy.' },
  _38: null }
```

Comment: You have to actually resolve the Promise to get the results, but I'm guessing that this ids are internal stuff of "fs"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use anything started with `_` as it's probably for internal use only.

btw, why use `_18` when it's a promise? you can always `.then` and get the result. See the example below

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir)

readdir('/Users/anh/Documents')
.then(function (files) {
  console.log(files)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right. 
Using .then() works to give me the list of files I want.  I was assuming that .then() would output the whole promise instead of just the list of file stored in readDirPromise._18. 
But it seems like .then() knows where to look and output the appropriate results.